# What is version of Symfony in Mautic 2

Tags: php, symfony, mautic

How to check version of Symfony PHP Framework in Mautic 2?

Mautic: https://github.com/mautic/mautic

Comment: Did you looked at composer.json? https://github.com/mautic/mautic/blob/staging/composer.json

Comment: Oh, I looked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The symfony version for Mautic is 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Mautic 4.4.9 uses symfony version 3.4.